# How to use jquery as CDN in React? Or how to access dynamic node(?)?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap, root, cdn

For some reason, the publishing result written in html and jquery without react is converted into react (component).

If you call the url directly with /sample2, it works without any problems. However, when moving using react-router-dom, the functions of various components do not work. For example date-picker etc.

I tried to access the datepicker by importing jquery with npm (import $ from 'jquery'), but it was not possible.

`$('#${startDatePickerId}').datePicker();// 1 $('#${startDatePickerId}')     .on('focus', (e) => { setStartDate(e.target.value); }) .on('keyup', (e) => { setStartDate(e.target.value); });// 2`
Method 1 is not accessible. Method 2 is possible, but that also does not access datePicker.

The picture below is the error when approaching method 1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHLHm.png)

These are written in the script under the div with id="root" in index.html.

`
// Class definition
var controls = {
leftArrow: '',
rightArrow: ''
}

```
var runDatePicker = function () {
  $('.cp-datepicker').datepicker({
      orientation: "bottom left",
      todayHighlight: true,
      templates: controls
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  runDatePicker();
});`
```

If you write the url directly in the address bar and move it, it seems to work well by reading the script of index.html once before rendering.

However, what I need is to apply it after the render is finished, or to call the script whenever components such as the date picker are displayed.

If so, first, how to use jquery as a CDN without using npm jquery, and second, how to access dynamically created jquery nodes (?),
Third, how can I run a script after rendering, and fourth, how can I run a script every time the components are shown?

The picture below is the information I see when I run the code below.

`console.log($('#${startDatePickerId'}));`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDzM.png)

I wonder if what I need is to be able to access 'jQuery341045109274036701152'.

be happy this year

I tried putting the script at the bottom of App.js, but couldn't get $ inside {} to run. This wasn't even npm jquery, but it was because you couldn't use jquery in App.js or its sub-components for the $ called in index.html.

I don't know how to use cdn jquery ($ in the script in index.html), which was used in a place other than npm jquery and not in react.

Comment: For reference, when using npm jquery, the following error pops up.

Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).datepicker is not a function